# How to run dart code using code-runner in vscode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Appologies if I am doing this wrong but I am trying to run dart code in vs code using code-runner extension.

note: language mode is set to dart

tried with `print('hello wold')`

this is the error I got back
`Error: Expected an identifier, but got ''hello world''.`

could someone help with what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So briefly I had to wrap the code in the `main` function, like below

```
main() {
  print('hello world');
}
```